# Cannot connect to a wcf service from a remote client

Tags: c#, wcf, vmware-player

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and C#.

**For my server:**
I have a console application that has the following code in Program.cs:

```
const string serviceURL = "http://localhost:1234/AccountService";

ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(
            typeof(AccountService),
            new Uri(serviceURL));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IAccountService),
            new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
            "");

serviceHost.Open();
```

The interface of the service is in a class library that is shared:

```
using Common.Types;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Common.Interfaces
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserAccountResult))]
    public interface IAccountService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        UserAccountResult Login(string userName, string password);

        [OperationContract]
        UserAccountResult CreateAccount(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

The UserAccountResult is an enum

The console app of the Server also has the implementation of the interface:

```
using Common.Types;

namespace Server
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        public UserAccountResult CreateAccount(string userName, string password)
        {
            return UserAccountResult.UserNameTaken;
        }

        public UserAccountResult Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            return UserAccountResult.CannotConnectToServer;
        }
    }
}
```

**For the client:**

```
const string serviceURL = "http://192.168.6.139:1234/AccountService";

ChannelFactory<IAccountService> channelFactory =
                new ChannelFactory<IAccountService>(
                new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
                new EndpointAddress(serviceURL));

IAccountService myService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Now the server exe is running on VMware Workstation 12 Player (with Windows 10).
When I try to connect to the server with the same computer that hosts the VMware (but not from the VMware itself) the connection works and I get a response. 
But when I try to connect with a different computer that is on the same network (same WIFI connection) it fails and I get an error that there was no endpoint listening.
I have to make a connection work from 2 different computers, this is a project for my first degree so any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
So instead of running the server from the VMware, I am running the server on the computer without Vmware. Then I get the ip from ipconfig and obviously it's a dynamic ip but when I try to connect to it from a different computer it works.
So what am I doing wrong here?
I can make a connection between the VMware and the computer it is hosted on. I can make a connection between 2 computers but I can't seem to make a connection between VMware and a different computer than the one hosting it.

Comment: 1234 is a strange port, probably you should add a Firewall rule

Comment: It didn't work with port 80 either

Comment: Made a rule still didn't work..